# NRF24L0 wireless modules

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+, wireless

I have two arduinos (one uno and another nano) with NRF24L0 modules attached to both and they are communicating between each other. All good.

However, I have a load of different ones and have switched them with the working receivers to test them but they just refuse to work despite the pinouts being correct.

Does the pinout vary between manufacturers or something else perhaps? What really perplexes me is that some of the modules I've tried are brand new (just taken out of the antistatic)

I have followed https://maniacbug.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/getting-started-rf24/

Any help would be really appriciated. Thanks

Comment: The library probably works fine, but I'd still recommend that you'd either download the updated version through the IDE or from https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/.

Comment: Second thing is that some modules are fake/counterfeits they do not work according to the specs in terms of registers, power usage, range, required decoupling and possibly in more aspects. See http://hackaday.com/2015/02/23/nordic-nrf24l01-real-vs-fake/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same kind of problems (even with new modules) when supplying them by mistake with 5v instead of 3,3V. It even happened that the system was working fine for days after the communication problems due to wrong power supply started to appear.

Also many people have reported similar problems(sometimes communicating, sometimes not) with this module due to poor built-in decoupling especially when using relatively long cables between arduino and module. Just to make sure, put a decoupling capacitor near the module's power and ground pins.

(this is more of a comment but I cannot comment due to reputation.)